# Android media player not playing from url

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I open the link on the web I can listen to the streaming but the Stream never loads on the phone but on the web it plays

Permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

My code:

```
String url = "http://n13.radiojar.com/5705c71sn2zuv?rj-ttl=5&rj-tok=AAABhPz0EysAQfb4iRmp2q_BTQ";    
     

 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
           // mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build());
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            // prepare async to not block main thread
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(player -> {
                 player.start();
                });
```

Comment: it was an error when i copied the url

Comment: Since you use `prepareAsync()`, you may need to register a listener and postpone your `start()` call until the prepare step is completed.

Comment: Have you noticed that it is literally what is in my code.

Comment: No, it is not. You are calling `start()` immediately after `prepareAsync()`. The prepare step will not have completed by the time `prepareAsync()` returns. Please see [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer?hl=en#managestate) for more on the prepare state. [The preceding section](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer?hl=en#preparingasync) covers `prepareAsync()` and how to register a listener to determine when it is OK to call `start()`.

Comment: in the same way continues the same.